# Ansible, exit without error after x amount of time

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to get ansible to exit without an error after a specified amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timeouts are normally treated as errors, but it is possible to ignore them by including `ignore_errors: yes` in the task. It means that the playbook will continue execution and in the next task we can check the result of the previous task and exit the play using `meta: end_play` with condition that there is some text related to timeout. The following example should make it clear:

```
- name: Try to download 1GB file very fast, but it is ok we will not manage
    get_url:
        url: "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip"
        dest: /some/folder/
    async: 10
    poll: 1
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: result

- name: Exit the play after timeout
    meta: end_play
    when: result.msg.find('did not complete within the requested time') != -1
```